Is the Landau-Lifshitz Equation Applicable to Single-Domain Magnetic Nanoparticles?
I am interested in studying the motion of the magnetic moment of single-domain magnetic nanoparticles in an external magnetic field. I came across the Landau-Lifshitz (LL) equation, which adds a nonlinear term to the traditional Larmor precession equation. On the other hand, I also learned that sufficiently small magnetic nanoparticles exhibit superparamagnetism, where their magnetic moments can flip back and forth between two directions. Given this condition, can I still use the LL equation to describe the motion of the magnetic moment of magnetic nanoparticles?
